# Is a PRG that reveals the first bit of the input secure

Tags: provable-security, pseudo-random-generator

Let $G:(0,1)^n \rightarrow (0,1)^{n+1}$ be a secure PRG. 
Define $G'(s):=s_1 ||G(s)_{2,...,n+1} $.
 ($||$ is concatenation, and the subscript $ _{2,...,n+1}$ means the last $n$ bits of $G$) 
I claim that $G'$ is a secure PRG, and my intuition is that if a distinguisher, say $D'$, could distinguish its output on a random seed from a truly random string of length $n+1$, I could break $G$. My reduction is:

$D(x)$:

1) Choose $b \in(0,1)$ randomly.

2) Return whatever $D'(b||x_{2,...,n+1})$ returns.

Clearly, if $x=r$ is truly random, then $b||x_{1,...,n+1}=r'$ is truly random and:
$Pr[D(r)=1]=Pr[D'(r')=1]$ 
The other case is where I have problem.

I've divided the probability into two events:
$Pr[D(G(s))=1]=$
$Pr[D(G(s))=1|b=s_1]\cdot Pr[b=s_1] + Pr[D(G(s))=1|b\neq s_1]\cdot Pr[b\neq s_1]=$
${1 \over 2}(Pr[D(G(s))=1|b=s_1] + Pr[D(G(s))=1|b\neq s_1])=$
${1 \over 2}(Pr[D'(G'(s))=1] + Pr[D(G(s))=1|b\neq s_1])$
Where the final transition is true because when $b=s_1$, we have exactly the definition of $G'$. 
However, I don't know how to handle the later addend. I noticed that when $b \neq s_1$, we give $D'$ an input of the form $G'(s) \oplus 10^n $.

***Questions***
1) Is my intuition correct? 
2) If so, is my reduction/proof correct? I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Suppose input $s = 0^n$ is submitted and $\mathcal{D}$ observes a response of $1 || \{0, 1\}^n$, what can $\mathcal{D}$ immediately infer with $Pr = 1$?

Comment: @puzzlepalace Nothing because D does not know s.

Comment: Remember that you don't need to compute $\mathrm{Pr}[D(G(s)) = 1]$ exactly, only to show that it it sufficiently far from $\mathrm{Pr}[D(r) = 1]$.